# Ember.js: Animating the deletion/removal of an item or record

Tags: animation, ember.js

I'm on Ember 1.13, [using ember-liquid-fire](http://ember-animation.github.io/liquid-fire/#/helpers/liquid-bind) for some other things, but with this, I want to animate deleting a record by fading or sliding it out. As it is right now, it just immediately disappears, which is a little jarring.

Here's the UI; the template is just using an `{{#each}}` helper to iterate over the model

[image: screen UI for records]

Here's my **delete action**:

```
delete: function(item) {
  this.get('model').removeObject(item);
  item.destroyRecord();
}
```

It was suggested elsewhere to use `{{liquid-bind}}` but I'm not sure where to put it in my markup since I'm using a table, and the `{{each}}` wraps the `<tr>`, so if I put the liquid helper around that, then there's `div`s as children of my table instead of rows.

If someone knows how to do this (using liquid-fire or another way), I'd love to know!

Answer (score 0):

The bind item should be change to trigger the liquid-fire.

Please take a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/09083b26ea467379466b475ddc2d2c31)

Comment: If I was using just divs, not a table, this might be fine, but as-is, it doesn't really help. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use liquid-fire, I went a simpler route of using [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/).

To do this, I had to create a component for my table rows. `liquid-fire` inserts `divs`, which of course messes up the table layout.

Inside my component, I just add the animation class, and when the animation is done, send the action to remove the item, like so:

```
//components/table-record.js
actions: {
    handleDelete(item) {
      this.$().addClass('animated zoomOut');
      this.$().one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', 
        () => {
          this.sendAction('deleteAction',item);
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

See [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/16c22cf720590233f7eb6d9b9bb91ad4?openFiles=components.table-record.js%2Ctemplates.components.hold-to-trigger.hbs) for full details.